# Error when try to get the last occurrence of an recurrent event in Outlook VSTO

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-redemption

I'm actually working with an VSTO Outlook Add-in in C# and Redemption. I try to get the occurrence of a recurrent event with this command: 

 `appointmentItem = recurrencePatterne.GetOccurence(recurrenceOriginalDate) as RDOAppointmentItem` 

I can get all occurrence with this command except the last one. It return an argument exception error which say that occurrence don't occur on XXX day (but I'm pretty sure that exist). Someone know how to get that last occurrence ?
P/S : Sorry for bad english :(

Comment: What version of Redemption are you using? Tis problem was fixed in version 5.14 - http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/history.htm

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko Thank you, it work like a magic :)